# NancyFx and unit testing Response.AsFile(...) fails with NotFound

Tags: c#, .net, testing, nancy

This is my (streamlined) Module

```
public class MyModule : NancyModule
{
    public MyModule() : base("/path")
    {
        Get["/{filename}"] = x =>
        {
            var fileName = (string)x.filename;
            var path = Path.Combine("files", fileName);
            if (!File.Exists(path)) throw new FileNotFoundException();

            return Response.AsFile(path);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works and sucessfully delivers the correct file to the browser.

Now I have written a test:

```
    [TestMethod, DeploymentItem("file.txt", "files")]
    public void CanDownloadFile()
    {

        var path = @"files\file.txt";
        Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(path));

        var bootstrapper = new MyBootstrapper();
        var browser = new Browser(bootstrapper); // from Nancy.Testing

        var result = browser.Get("/path/file.txt", with =>
        {
            with.HttpRequest();
        });

        var body = result.Body.AsString();
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
    }
```

With this code my test fails because the StatusCode is `NotFound` instead of `OK`

I even tried to replace `Response.AsFile()` with

```
var info = new FileInfo(path);
return new GenericFileResponse(info.FullName);
```

and triple checked the file really exists physically on disk wile executing my test.

What's the problem?

Comment: I know it is very old. But I want to know have you able to solve the issue?

Comment: @KokiralaSudheer I think I changed my code to use `return Response.FromStream(stream).AsAttachment(fileName, contentType);` You can figure out the contentType with `MimeTypes.GetMimeType(filePath)` (have a look at `GenericFileResponse.cs` from nancy.

Answer (score 1):

Is the file "file.txt" included in de Solution? Include this.

In the file properties in Visual Studio change the property Copy to Output Directory to Copy if newer.

But you don't need to create a Module to do this. Yo can manage static content in the Nancy bootstrapper. Here is the documentation https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Managing-static-content

Doing this, you don´t need to test that.